# Unstable Wifi with Ubuntu 14.04 and Realtek Wifi Adapter

Tags: 14.04, dhcp, realtek, wicd

I've been fighting with this problem for a couple weeks now. I've made some progress, but haven't gotten to the point of a truly stable internet connection via WIFI.

Unfortunately, the issue is at work, and I do not have access to router configuration. I'm hoping to narrow down the issue to something on my laptop.

Steps I've done so far..

1. Switched to using Wicd instead of Network Manager
2. Using static DNS of 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
3. Updated adapter drivers

This got me to a point that I could at least connect to the internet, but I'm still dropping every 5-10 minutes, and DHCP has trouble resolving. Usually takes me 3-4 attempts to connect/reconnect.

Here's the results of the wireless script I've found:

```
  ########## wireless info START ##########

  Report from: 09 Feb 2016 14:58 EST -0500

  Booted last: 09 Feb 2016 14:54 EST -0500

  Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

  ##### release ###########################

  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
  Release:  14.04
  Codename: trusty

  ##### kernel ############################

  Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

  Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

  ##### desktop ###########################

  sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

  Could not be determined.

  ##### lspci #############################

  05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

  06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Device [1d05:100e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

  ##### lsusb #############################

  Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:053a Acer, Inc 
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

  ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

  ##### rfkill ############################

  0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
  1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

  ##### lsmod #############################

  rtl8821ae             229376  0 
  btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
  rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
  rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
  mac80211              712704  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
  cfg80211              524288  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
  mxm_wmi                16384  0 
  wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi

  ##### interfaces ########################

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  ##### ifconfig ##########################

  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
            UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
            inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:1312 errors:0 dropped:91 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:1019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:723082 (723.0 KB)  TX bytes:186479 (186.4 KB)

  ##### iwconfig ##########################

  eth0      no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.

  wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Company Inc"  
            Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]>   
            Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
            Encryption key:off
            Power Management:off
            Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
            Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
            Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:45   Missed beacon:0

  ##### route #############################

  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
  10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0

  ##### resolv.conf #######################

  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4

  ##### network managers ##################

  Installed:

    Wicd

  Running:

    None found.

  ##### NetworkManager info ###############

  NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

  ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

  [main]
  NetworkingEnabled=true
  WirelessEnabled=true
  WWANEnabled=true
  WimaxEnabled=true

  ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

  [main]
  plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
  dns=dnsmasq

  [ifupdown]
  managed=false

  ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

  [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Company Inc]] (600 root)
  [connection] id=Company Inc | type=802-11-wireless
  [802-11-wireless] ssid=Company Inc | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
  [ipv4] method=auto
  [ipv6] method=auto

  [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Toy Story]] (600 root)
  [connection] id=Toy Story | type=802-11-wireless
  [802-11-wireless] ssid=Toy Story | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
  [ipv4] method=auto
  [ipv6] method=auto

  [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VidToy]] (600 root)
  [connection] id=VidToy | type=802-11-wireless
  [802-11-wireless] ssid=VidToy | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
  [ipv4] method=auto
  [ipv6] method=ignore

  ##### iw reg get ########################

  Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

  country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

  ##### iwlist channels ###################

  eth0      no frequency information.

  lo        no frequency information.

  wlan0     24 channels in total; available frequencies :
            Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
            Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
            Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
            Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
            Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
            Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
            Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
            Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
            Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
            Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
            Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
            Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
            Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
            Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
            Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
            Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
            Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
            Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
            Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
            Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
            Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
            Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
            Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
            Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
            Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

  ##### iwlist scan #######################

  eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

  lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

  Channel occupancy:

        4   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
        1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
        13   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
        2   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
        1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
        1   APs on   Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
        3   APs on   Frequency:5.765 GHz (Channel 153)

  wlan0     Scan completed :
            Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"Company Inc"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=00000092cc2ae578
                      Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'DGCI' [AC2]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"DGCI"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000000630233ef88
                      Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'HP-Print-67-Officejet Pro 8600' [AC3]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"HP-Print-67-Officejet Pro 8600"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                                9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=00000092ca802021
                      Extra: Last beacon: 200ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'VIETV-WDC' [AC4]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"VIETV-WDC"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000018199e4d4ae0
                      Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'ASUS_MVR' [AC5]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"ASUS_MVR"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000004b50e841916
                      Extra: Last beacon: 516ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 06 - Address: <MAC '' [AC6]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                                36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000000b94529a03a
                      Extra: Last beacon: 184ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'KPSOFTNET' [AC7]>
                      Channel:6
                      Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                      Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"KPSOFTNET"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000000055696e398
                      Extra: Last beacon: 144ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'HP-Print-3B-Officejet Pro 8620' [AC8]>
                      Channel:1
                      Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                      Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"HP-Print-3B-Officejet Pro 8620"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                                11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=00000063008f11f8
                      Extra: Last beacon: 7468ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'Alavi Law' [AC9]>
                      Channel:1
                      Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                      Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"Alavi Law"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                                9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000000403e01efbf
                      Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                      IE: WPA Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Cell 10 - Address: <MAC 'Aumvis' [AC10]>
                      Channel:1
                      Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                      Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                      Encryption key:on
                      ESSID:"Aumvis"
                      Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                      Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      Mode:Master
                      Extra:tsf=000000630079c796
                      Extra: Last beacon: 11964ms ago
                      IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                          Group Cipher : CCMP
                          Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                          Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

  ##### module infos ######################

  [rtl8821ae]
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
  firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
  description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
  license:        GPL
  author:         Realtek WlanFAE   <wlanfae@realtek.com>
  srcversion:     5FCDD84BF572D3F1AFBE47E
  depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512
  parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
   (bool)
  parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
   (bool)
  parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
   (bool)
  parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
   (bool)
  parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
   (bool)
  parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
  parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
   (bool)

  [rtl_pci]
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
  description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
  license:        GPL
  author:         Larry Finger  <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
  author:         Realtek WlanFAE   <wlanfae@realtek.com>
  author:         lizhaoming    <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
  srcversion:     A25DC6D8C53D55DA133BC49
  depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512

  [rtlwifi]
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
  description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
  license:        GPL
  author:         Larry Finger  <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
  author:         Realtek WlanFAE   <wlanfae@realtek.com>
  author:         lizhaoming    <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
  srcversion:     35016235A31CEB1854418E1
  depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512

  [mac80211]
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
  license:        GPL
  description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
  srcversion:     1261743510839D352D1D895
  depends:        cfg80211
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512
  parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
  parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
  parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
  parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
  parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
  parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

  [cfg80211]
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
  description:    wireless configuration support
  license:        GPL
  author:         Johannes Berg
  srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
  depends:        
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512
  parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
  parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

  ##### module parameters #################

  [rtl8821ae]
  debug: 0
  disable_watchdog: N
  fwlps: Y
  ips: Y
  msi: Y
  swenc: N
  swlps: N

  [mac80211]
  beacon_loss_count: 7
  ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
  max_nullfunc_tries: 2
  max_probe_tries: 5
  minstrel_vht_only: Y
  probe_wait_ms: 500

  [cfg80211]
  cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
  ieee80211_regdom: 00

  ##### /etc/modules ######################

  lp
  rtc

  ##### modprobe options ##################

  [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
  blacklist ath_pci

  [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
  blacklist evbug
  blacklist usbmouse
  blacklist usbkbd
  blacklist eepro100
  blacklist de4x5
  blacklist eth1394
  blacklist snd_intel8x0m
  blacklist snd_aw2
  blacklist i2c_i801
  blacklist prism54
  blacklist bcm43xx
  blacklist garmin_gps
  blacklist asus_acpi
  blacklist snd_pcsp
  blacklist pcspkr
  blacklist amd76x_edac

  [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
  alias net-pf-3 off
  alias net-pf-6 off
  alias net-pf-9 off
  alias net-pf-11 off
  alias net-pf-12 off
  alias net-pf-19 off
  alias net-pf-21 off
  alias net-pf-36 off

  [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
  remove iwlwifi \
  (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
  && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

  [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
  softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

  ##### rc.local ##########################

  exit 0

  ##### pm-utils ##########################

  ##### udev rules ########################

  [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
  # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
  # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8821 (rtl8821ae)
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

  ##### dmesg #############################

  [   44.651708] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
  [   44.909250] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
  [   47.362136] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]>
  [   47.362499] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [   47.363647] wlan0: authenticated
  [   47.365703] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [   47.371174] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
  [   47.371365] wlan0: associated
  [   76.728582] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
  [   77.007632] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
  [   79.464468] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]>
  [   79.464833] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [   79.465988] wlan0: authenticated
  [   79.468083] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [   79.469061] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
  [   79.469252] wlan0: associated
  [  108.704493] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
  [  108.977864] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
  [  111.430663] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]>
  [  111.431031] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [  111.431705] wlan0: authenticated
  [  111.434256] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [  111.435209] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
  [  111.435398] wlan0: associated
  [  132.661319] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
  [  132.910502] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
  [  140.982102] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]>
  [  140.982467] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [  140.983077] wlan0: authenticated
  [  140.985662] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (try 1/3)
  [  140.986552] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
  [  140.986745] wlan0: associated
  [  162.151930] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC22]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
  [  162.397744] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
  [  176.124003] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]>
  [  176.124458] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
  [  176.126013] wlan0: authenticated
  [  176.127667] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
  [  176.131569] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Company Inc' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
  [  176.131767] wlan0: associated

  ########## wireless info END ############
```

Any insight/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245164&p=13222964#post13222964

Comment: Tried that previously. No noticeable difference. :-\

Answer (score 0):

You have the same hardware as i do so i hope this works for you.
Open a terminal and type the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

If you find the wifi isn't as stable as you'd expect, use this command after booting (yes everytime sorry).

```
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Good luck and happy coding!